# Can someone explain these random numbers?

Tags: random, numbers

I have some code that produces random numbers for an AI but I am unsure how the percentage sign works.

This is my code that creates the numbers:

```
ey[i]=rand()%950;
ex[i]=rand()%300+800;
ev[i]=rand()%10-5;
```

Im using C++ in Visual Studio

Thanks in advance

Comment: most languages use `%` as the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator. But since you haven't provided any details about WHAT language this is, that's about the best you'll get.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that haha. It's C++

Answer (score 1):

The percentage is usually a Modulus operator, which you can think of as the remainder after division.

For example

```
10 % 3 = 1
```

because 3 goes in to 10 3 times with 1 left over.

Your code gets a random number and then divides it by the right number, saving the remainder.